# Are Windows Forms CheckBoxes smart about whether to refresh or not when setting Checked?

Tags: winforms

If I set a Windows Forms `CheckBox.Checked = true`, and it's already true, does the widget redraw itself?

I would expect not, if it's just directly setting the value as there will be no change. But I can imagine that there might be some magic code in there that sets a dirty flag upon setting the value, regardless of what it already was.

I just want to know if I should be doing stuff like this to prevent extra refreshes:

```
if (TheBox.Checked != checkBool)
{
    TheBox.Checked = checkBool;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Checked value doesn't change, the `Paint` event doesn't fire, so I assume that means it isn't redrawing itself. You can see this by handling the `CheckBox.Paint` event and putting a breakpoint in the handler method.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Good point about handling Paint to verify!